String value length exceeds the maximum allowed
I'm sending 28MB CSV data as Base64 encoded string in json format to REST API. Below is example of request body.
{
   "csvData" : "ReallyLargeBase64EncodedString"
}

I get this exception when request is sent to API.
JSON parse error: String value length (20051112) exceeds the maximum allowed (20000000, from `StreamReadConstraints.getMaxStringLength()`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: String value length (20051112) exceeds the maximum allowed (20000000, from `StreamReadConstraints.getMaxStringLength()`)

Jackson core version: 2.16.0
Is it possible to increase default size from 20000000 to custom value?

Why would you Base64 encode CSV - it's text?

The question is kinda moot: That is a bad thing to do. You need to read the JSON as streaming JSON, and, rather specially, that the strings themselves are streamed. Then you can wrap the stream in a Base64 decoder and then wrap the output of that to whatever you wanna do with it. Wanna save it to disk? Swell - make an OutputStream and .transferTo. Whatever you do, the RAM load of your server should remain a few kb even if instead of 28MB you had 28TB.

Don’t use JSON.  Your REST API should produce a response whose Content-Type is text/csv.  This allows your code to stream the data instead of loading all of it into program memory.

The work-around is to configure StreamReadConstraints; see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34709 for an example.  But any API that requires you to send massive CSVs wrapped in JSON is badly designed.  It would be better to fix the API design than implement a hacky workaround on (probably) both the client and server sides ... and suffer the resulting performance hit.

So after some investigation found out that <2.15 jackson-core versions didn't have any limitations to upload string data. StreamReadConstraints.java class is introduced from jackson-core 2.15 version which has default 20 million character limit. Hence, character limit issue never occurred in older versions of my product.

fyi a base64 string about 30% larger than the source string.
